# age calculation in vb.net coding

Tags: vb.net

net coding and i am really stuck in this basic age calculation. I have created a form field and in a groupbox it should display the age of a person. The biggest problem i am facing with the code is factoring in the month. I have tried all types such as using DateInterval.Month but still no luck. Here MyEntPatient.DOB is the DOB of patient

```
Dim Years As Integer
Dim BDAY As New DateTime(Now.Year)
BDAY = MyEntPatient.DOB
If (BDAY > Now) Then
    Years = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, MyEntPatient.DOB, Now) - 1
Else
    Years = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, MyEntPatient.DOB, Now)
End If

Me.gpxPatientDetails.Text = " Age:" + Years.ToString()
```

Comment: If only the year changes then only the age changes but not the month. I hoped the query bday > now will solve it but no luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to have the difference of the date, I think this example help you:

```
Dim birthday As New DateTime(12, 12, 2012)
Dim difference As DateTime = DateTime.Now - birthday
Dim years As Integer = difference.Years
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have problem with bigger/smaller age, because someone doesn't have a birthday this year (born in December for example), you can try this:

```
Dim bday As New DateTime(2010, 1, 25) 
Dim months As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, bday, Now)
Dim years As Integer = months / 12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Function AgeCalculator(ByVal FromDate As String, Optional flgyearOnly As Boolean = False) As String '23/11/2017
    If Not IsDate(FromDate) Then Return ""
    Dim tmpYear As String = "", tmpMonth As String = "", tmpdiff As Integer = 0
        Dim tmpAge As String = ""
        tmpdiff = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, CDate(Format2DateMMM(FromDate)), Now)
        If tmpdiff <= 0 Then Return ""
        If tmpdiff > 0 And tmpdiff <= 29 Then
            Return tmpdiff & " Days"
        End If
        If tmpdiff = 30 Then
            Return " 1 Month"
        End If

        tmpYear = tmpdiff / 365
        If InStr(tmpYear, ".") > 0 Then
            tmpYear = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(tmpYear, InStr(tmpYear, ".") - 1)
        End If

        If Val(tmpYear) = 0 Then tmpYear = ""
    If Val(tmpYear) > 0 Then
        tmpAge = tmpYear & " years"
        If flgyearOnly Then Return tmpAge
    End If

    tmpdiff = (tmpdiff - (Val(tmpYear) * 365))

        tmpMonth = tmpdiff / 30
        If InStr(tmpMonth, ".") > 0 Then
            tmpMonth = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(tmpMonth, InStr(tmpMonth, ".") - 1)
        End If

        If Val(tmpMonth) = 0 Then tmpMonth = ""

        If tmpMonth > 0 Then
        tmpAge &= "  " & tmpMonth & " Months"
    End If

        tmpdiff = (tmpdiff - (Val(tmpMonth) * 30))
        If Val(tmpdiff) > 0 Then
            tmpAge &= "  " & tmpdiff & " Days"
        End If
        Return tmpAge: End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A perfectly working VB.NET code for calculating age using "DateTimePicker" and "TextBox". Gives exact calculation for both Leap years and normal years.

```
Function CalculateDOB(DOB As Date) As String
        Try
            If pkDOB.Value <> Date.Today Then
                Dim DOBYear As Integer = pkDOB.Value.Year
                Dim DOBMonth As Integer = pkDOB.Value.Month
                Dim DOBDay As Integer = pkDOB.Value.Day

                Dim CurrentYear As Integer = Date.Today.Year
                Dim CurrentMonth As Integer = Date.Today.Month
                Dim CurrentDay As Integer = Date.Today.Day

                Dim MonthEndings() As Integer = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
                If DOBDay > CurrentDay Then
                    CurrentMonth = CurrentMonth - 1
                    CurrentDay = CurrentDay + MonthEndings(DOBMonth - 1)
                End If
                If DOBMonth > CurrentMonth Then
                    CurrentYear = CurrentYear - 1
                    CurrentMonth = CurrentMonth + 12
                End If
                Dim AgeDay As Integer = CurrentDay - DOBDay
                Dim AgeMonth As Integer = CurrentMonth - DOBMonth
                Dim AgeYear As Integer = CurrentYear - DOBYear
                Dim age As String = AgeYear & "y" & AgeMonth & "m" & AgeDay & "d"
                txtAge.Text = age
            End If
        Catch ex as exception
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: what about leap years?

Comment: Those if conditions are meant to filter and calculate leap years. Just test this by giving some values. Add breakpoints at If's and you'll know clearly, how it calculates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your contributions

Answer (score 0):

A bit old posting, but the question is not!
Typically the 'age' is the whole years completed:

```
Dim DOB As Date = DateValue("1970-10-28")
Dim Tday As Date = DateValue("2022-02-21")
Console.WriteLine(
       Int((CInt(Tday.ToString("yyyyMMdd")) - CInt(DOB.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))) / 10000)
       )
```